# Delete image with AJAX without page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax

i would like to remove uploaded image from the server with AJAX and without page reaload.

I tried to write some code but without any results.

Here is my HTML code:

```
              <div class="row"> 
                @if(!empty($service_data) && !empty($service_data->sd_folder))
                @foreach(File::files(Helper::getUserUploadFolder($service_data->sd_uid).'services/'.$service_data->sd_folder) as $others_img)
                    {{--*/ $img_filename = pathinfo($others_img)['filename']; 
                           $img_basename = pathinfo($others_img)['basename']; 
                        if($img_filename == 'main') continue; /*--}}                        

               <div class="col-sm-4" id="{{$img_basename}}">
                 <div class="example">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img class="cover-image overlay-figure overlay-scale" src="{{asset($others_img)}}">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <p><a class="btn btn-primary margin-right-5 img_delete" data-filename="{{$img_basename}}" role="button">DELETE</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div> 
              </div>

                @endforeach
                @endif  
             </div>
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
        var service_folder = $('#service_folder').val();


    $('body').on('click', '.img_delete', function(){

        var filename = $(this).data('filename');
        var this_div = $(this);

        if((service_folder === '') || (service_folder == 'undefined')) return false;
        else if((filename === '') || (filename == 'undefined')) return false;

        var img_delete_ajax = $.get("/en/ajax/user/img_upload_delete",{main_folder: 'services', imgs_folder: service_folder, filename: filename}, function(data){
                                console.log("delete", data);
                              });

        img_delete_ajax.always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success"){
                $('#'+filename).fadeOut(250);

            }


        });

    });
```

Can anybody recomend me or help me with this function?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried, but it does not help :/

Comment: Are you sure that `/en/ajax/user/img_upload_delete` handles the delete properly? does it create the same path since you're only passing the base_name? Have you tried running the delete page on it's own or `var_dump` the params that are passed there? You can see it in the network response tab in the console. Can you see what file you're trying to delete? Does your webserver user (apache etc) have permission to delete files in that folder? can you post some snippets of your delete page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var service_folder = $('#service_folder').val();

$('.img_delete').on('click', function() {

    var filename = $(this).data('filename');
    var this_div = $(this);

    if ((service_folder === '') || (service_folder == 'undefined')) return false;
    else if ((filename === '') || (filename == 'undefined')) return false;

    $.get("/en/ajax/user/img_upload_delete", {main_folder: 'services',   imgs_folder: service_folder,filename: filename}).done(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            $('#' + filename).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
});
```

After success send a parameter {success:true} from your server. Don't forget to set your CONTENT_TYPE to "application/json" or you can use 
JSON.parse(data) to convert string into json.

Comment: My code is function, its remove image from the server but do not hide box after click on delete button. I need to refresh page manualy.
And dont understand why... :/

Comment: The reason maybe the special character used in your div id. Remove all the special characters such as .jpg etc. `id="{{$img_basename}}"`